# Is it possible to see how many people uninstalled my app on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Basically, on the Windows Phone developer site it shows how many installs your app has, but is there any way to see how many of these people have uninstalled it; so that you can see how many are actually using it?

Comment: I don't believe this metric is available but that doesn't mean you can't datamine on people. For example, in many of my apps I have them phone home and pass statistics to me. You could easily assign a unique guid to each install then when the app phones home save the guid. You could then cross reference how many guids you have against how many installs you have. That will give you an idea of how many people are actively using your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This metric is not available in DevCenter. But you can use [Distimo](http://distimo.com) and/or [Flurry](http://flurry.com) to get user retention, conversion rates etc.